# Filter function and ignoring a condition

Tags: google-sheets

I used the following formula to filter a date range between the date entered in A3 and date entered in B3 and also the data entered in C3 that matches column D

```
=Filter('Sort Violations'!P2:P,'Sort Violations'!C2:C>=Int(A3),'Sort Violations'!C2:C<=Int(B3),'Sort Violations'!D2:D=C3)
```

I'd like the formula to work where if C3 is empty/blank, the filter still pulls all data from the other conditions in the filter (date range).  I think it needs a `len` in the formula but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 1):

try this if it works for you:

```
=IF(LEN(C3), FILTER('Sort Violations'!P2:P, 'Sort Violations'!C2:C>=INT(A3), 
                                            'Sort Violations'!C2:C<=INT(B3),
                                            'Sort Violations'!D2:D=C3), )
```